# can't make geometric shapes to move in Java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, shapes

I'm all new to this site and to Java, so please be lenient.

I'm writing a program that allows to draw different type of shapes with a button click and after hitting another button move/stop/reset them.

I've made already the most part I think (the shapes are correctly creating and storing in an arraylist, the same with the reset, which clear the screen), but I can't figure out how to make them move.I got a function for movement but can't find a way to make the shapes form the arraylist to move. Can anyone give me a little advise.

Thanks

P.S. If there is something wrong/bad coding and needs to be fixed I'll be grateful if you will point at them.

Here is my code:

MyShape class is for creating different shapes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public abstract class MyShape extends Component {

    protected Color color;
    private int x, y, dimX, dimY;
    public Random random = new Random();

    public MyShape(int x, int y, int dimX, int dimY){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dimX = dimX;
        this.dimY = dimY;
        color = new Color(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255));
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getDimX() {
        return dimX;
    }

    public void setDimX(int dimX) {
        this.dimX = dimX;
    }

    public int getDimY() {
        return dimY;
    }

    public void setDimY(int dimY) {
        this.dimY = dimY;
    }
}
```

CircleShape - creating circles.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class CircleShape extends MyShape {

    public CircleShape(int x, int y, int dimX, int dimY) {
        super(x, y, dimX, dimY);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getDimX(), getDimY());
    }
}
```

RectangleShape - rectangles

```
import java.awt.*;

public class RectangleShape extends MyShape {

    public RectangleShape(int x, int y, int dimX, int dimY) {
        super(x, y, dimX, dimY);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getDimX(), getDimY());
    }
}
```

and the DrawShape class which handles pretty much everything

```
    public class DrawShapes extends JPanel {

    private JButton addButton, resumeAllButton, stopAllButton, resetButton;
    private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
    private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 530;
    private int x, y, dimX, dimY;
    private Random random = new Random();
    public List<MyShape> myShapeList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyShape>();
    private Timer timer = null;
    public boolean move = false;

    public DrawShapes() {

        this.setLayout(null);
        addButton = new JButton("Add Shape");
        resumeAllButton = new JButton("Resume Shapes");
        stopAllButton = new JButton("Stop All Shapes");
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");

        addButton.setBounds(40, 20, 150, 30);
        resumeAllButton.setBounds(230, 20, 150, 30);
        stopAllButton.setBounds(420, 20, 150, 30);
        resetButton.setBounds(610, 20, 150, 30);
        this.add(addButton);
        this.add(resumeAllButton);
        this.add(stopAllButton);
        this.add(resetButton);

        stopAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                move = false;
            }
        });

        resumeAllButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                move = true;

            }
        });

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        init();
                    }
                };
                thread.start();

            }
        });

        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < myShapeList.size(); i++) {
                    myShapeList.clear();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public void moveIt() {

        boolean directionUp = random.nextBoolean();
        boolean directionLeft = random.nextBoolean();
        boolean directionDown = !directionUp;
        boolean directionRight = !directionLeft;

        while (move) {
            if (x <= 0) {
                directionRight = true;
                directionLeft = false;
            }
            if (x >= FRAME_WIDTH - dimX) {
                directionRight = false;
                directionLeft = true;
            }
            if (y <= 70) {
                directionUp = false;
                directionDown = true;
            }
            if (y >= FRAME_HEIGHT + 50 - dimY) {
                directionUp = true;
                directionDown = false;
            }
            if (directionUp)
                y--;
            if (directionDown)
                y++;
            if (directionLeft)
                x--;
            if (directionRight)
                x++;
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        dimX = (random.nextInt(FRAME_WIDTH) + 100) / 2;
        dimY = (random.nextInt(FRAME_HEIGHT) + 100) / 2;

        while (x <= 0)
            x = (random.nextInt(FRAME_WIDTH) - dimX);
        while (y <= 70)
            y = (random.nextInt(FRAME_HEIGHT) - dimY);
        int choice = 0;
        choice = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                RectangleShape rectangleShape = new RectangleShape(x, y, dimX, dimY);
                myShapeList.add(rectangleShape);
                timer.start();
                repaint();
                break;
            case 2:
                CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape(x, y, dimX, dimY);
                myShapeList.add(circleShape);
                repaint();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 70, 800, 530);
        for (MyShape aMyShapeList : myShapeList) {
            aMyShapeList.draw(g);

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.add(new DrawShapes());
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jFrame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - jFrame.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - jFrame.getSize().height / 2);
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: Once you have this working as intended you might want to ask again (with the updated code) on the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), so that this question can be focused on getting it to work. I cannot really make sense of your `moveIt` logic so I must ask - what are you trying to do? Do you want to let the user drag shapes, do you want to randomize their position, do you want to animate them across the screen?

Comment: yes I want animate them across the screen.

when creating a shape it must have random dimensions and to be drawn in random x,y coordinates. the moveIt logic must move the shapes in random directions, bounce when reaching the bounds of frame and change direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you posted I can see that you are not calling your `moveIt()` method anywhere.

You have the right idea of how to move things around. The basic algorithm is:

1. Calculate new positions
2. Repaint the view

I can recommend you do the following:

- You are currently calling your init method in a thread. I am not sure this is needed. Remove the thread logic and just call the method on the main thread.
- Introduce another button tho start the actual animation. When clicking, create a thread that will call your `moveIt()` method.

Comment: You are right, I'm not calling the method `moveIt()` because I can't understand where to put it, actually I've putted it in the addResumeButton actionListener but when I press the button my program freezes.
As for the Thread thanks for the advice :)

Comment: It most likely freezes, because you enter in an endless loop and can't change the `move` flag to false. Try and using a thread to call `moveIt()`. This way you won't block the UI with the loop and you will be able to stop the moving once you put the flag down.

Comment: OK, I'll try it when I'll get back home, and will let you know what happened.

Comment: Well, it's not freezing anymore, but the shapes that I create doesn't move... can't understand why, any other suggestions?

What I did is on the resumAllButton except making `move` to true, I've added a new `Thread` and call the `moveIt`.

Comment: I would try and debug your `moveIt()` method to see if it is executed the way you expect. Maybe there is something wrong in the position calculations, maybe some other part of the code. Debugging is the only way to see how this part of the code works.

Comment: I've managed to make it work, anyway thanks for your help,

I've made a class `Move`,placed the `repaint()` method in it, putted in a thread and it worked.